# jquery Regex : how to validate address and city using jquery Regex

Tags: jquery, regex

i need to validate address1 , address 2 and city using jquery regex..

Used for a street address. Legal Characters: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, hyphen, slash and single space. Illegal Character: leading space, trailing space, adjacent spaces, and other symbols.

Used for a city. Legal Characters: A-Z, a-z, and single space. Illegal Character: leading space, trailing space, adjacent spaces, and symbols.

sample:

Address1: { required: true, regex: "A-Za-z0-9*" }

Comment: You can't, and shouldn't. You'll never write something generic enough to handle all cases. Accept whatever the user enters provided it's at least two words long. You also shouldn't reject an address because it has leading or trailing spaces. That's super annoying for the user. Just trim it.

Comment: i got this one...but its not working.. [A-Za-z0-9](?[A-Za-z0-9\-/])*

Comment: @meager, post your comment as an answer :)

Comment: @yogee, did you read meagar's comment?

Comment: @ j.p, ya but its my task i hav to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're doing this for some project, so you should really figure out how to do the regex on your own.

However, I will tell you.  It is my understanding that you need to give the regex for each field separately and they will be validated separately.

```
//Address 1 & 2 regex
regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] ?([a-zA-Z0-9-\/]|[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] )*[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]$/
```

Start with a letter/number/dash/slash followed by an optional space.  Follow with any number of l/n/d/s or l/n/d/s followed by a space (this forces there to be only one space because each space must be preceded by a l/n/d/s).  End with l/n/d/s.

```
//City is much easier:
regex: /^[a-zA-z] ?([a-zA-z]|[a-zA-z] )*[a-zA-z]$/
```

Pretty much the same as above, just without worrying about numbers, dashes, and slashes.

Check out unit tests: http://jsfiddle.net/LJCzR/4/

As stated above, though if you are not doing this for academic reasons, then I wouldn't validate on leading/trailing space or duplicate space at all.  I would silently clean it.  Additionally, you simply can't account for every case.  This kind of validation is just annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Yogee, I'd be very cautious about validating addresses with a regex. I actually work at [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com) where our specialty is address validation and I know from experience that a regex *simply is not sufficient* unless, of course, you want to frustrate users for those percentage of addresses that don't fit a regex like above but are still valid, or if you want to accept faulty information from users that still DOES fit the regex.

In other words, I have come to learn quite quickly that regex is not a comprehensive, functional alternative to true verification. May I suggest you look into an easy-to-use API that does this for you? Meaning: somebody (who is certified by a government agency) has already done all the hard stuff for you. There's a lot to factor in when validating an address.... a LOT.

[Here's some documentation](http://smartystreets.com/how-to/regex-street-address).

So of course I'll recommend a service I've worked on, [LiveAddress](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/) (which is free and super-easy with Javascript) -- and if you have any further questions I'll be happy to personally help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great Regexp tutorial explaining how the syntax works and how to do many type of validations. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/.

Comment: There are so many wrong things in that article that I don't know where to start...besides it's not solving the OP's problem (but interestingly enough, he still accepted it. Funny).

Comment: An interesting website..however it does not make any mention of address or city validation.  I also disagree with a couple of the validators, namely the email and password.  Password is just semantic: it should be of unlimited length and allow any special characters.  The email regex is leaving out a lot of valid email characters, and he doesn't present his regexes as case insensitive!

Comment: This is a great starting point for someone who is not too familiar with Regexp. Regardless of the way it's used, it will give OP good  understanding on how things work in regexp.